# why am i encountering index out of range error in this code

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        char[] ch = new char[] { };
        for(int i = 0; i<x;i++)
        {
            ch[i] = 'o';
        }
        foreach(char item in ch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        string a = "w";
        string m = new string(ch);
        Console.Write(a + m + a);
```

expected result was "wow" if 1 is entered, woow if 2 is entered and so on..
but what i am getting is index out of range error.

Comment: `new char[] {}`creates an array of size 0, so there's no room for your o's. You need to create it so it's big enough to hold the number of o's you want.

Comment: When iterating over an array, it's usually best to use the `Length` property: `for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)`

Comment: thanks for help.. it really helped.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you need to declare the size of the `char` array (or any array).

To correct the code, just change one line.

```
char[] ch = new char[] { };    // incorrect, initialised with size = 0
```

to

```
char[] ch = new char[x];       // initialise the array with size = x
```

---

If you don't know what size the array will be at runtime then I would consider using the generic [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

`List<T>` implements many helpful methods, such as `Add()` which allows you to modify the size of the collection at runtime.  Other `List` methods you may find useful include: `Count()`, `AddRange()`, `Clear()`, `IndexOf()` and `Remove()`.

Then you could do something like:

```
List<char> ch = new List<char>();
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    ch.Add('o');
}
```